# Passing private variables from class isntance into method outside class?

Tags: python

I have a Class A, with the following method as part of the class:

```
def combine(self, reduce_function):
     self.__combine = reduce_function(self.__values)
```

I have to create the reduce_function outside of the class as part of a different method, how do I access the self.__values that have been passed ?

Comment: What? They are being passed to the function, you access them like any other argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, it seems you are passing `self.__values` as a parameter to the `reduce_function` so you can use that parameter.

For instance, if you define a dummy reduce function:

```
def print_param(param):
    print('Values passed via parameter: {}'.format(param))
```

You can then do:

```
a_object.combine(print_param)
```

And see `self.__values` from `a_object` get printed.

Answer (score 0):

The name of private variable in a class has been changed. You can try this to achieve your goal.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class test:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__value = 'a'

def func1(value):
    print value

a = test()
func1(a._test__value)
```